# Factory Design Pattern with Some Completely Similar Methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, factory

I am using the factory design pattern in Java. 
According to this pattern, every classes implement an interface and all its methods in the way that they like.

Now, my question is, assume the situation that there are some methods that are exactly the same and some methods which are not (and should be implemented separately)

In this scenario, can I use Factory design pattern. 
If no, how can I benefit from the property of deferring instantiation to subclasses? 
If yes, where should I implement the common methods?

Comment: Where did you get that pattern states for implementing interfaces?

Comment: So the solution is abstract classes! you are right :)

Comment: It doesn't matter what it returns I could get the interfaces from the factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where should I implement the common methods?

In an abstract class which implements your interface.  You implement common methods and leave methods which are not.

Comment: And other classes should extends that abstract class?

Comment: Correct. You can have a tree structure of abstract classes if you wish. ;)

Comment: I didn't get how to do it. let me copy some code in the question and you let me know where I made the mistake, please :)